# store select not running because of ngIf statement

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am busy with MeteorJS and RxJS, which is exiting but also a bit confusing sometimes.
My current question is an Angular NgRx question only, not related to MeteorJS.

As you can see in the example, there is a `ngIf` based on `showChannels`. This boolean is set to `false`. However, the async for loop inside is referenced to  my store.select.
However, operators in the pipe are never executed, because of the ngIf. It seems to be a deadlock.
How do I enable the subscription to start working?

When I do a search it adds Channels to the store, and the `store.select` would work if there would be no `ngIf` around the `ngFor` loop.

When I recplace the if to `*ngIf="(channels$ | async) ?.length !== 0"` it will work, but then the `tap` is run twice when I do one search.

The commented store.select with the subscribe actually works well using the `markForCheck`. Any suggestions on what the best solution while not using the `subscribe`?

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'podcast-search',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, // turn this off if you want everything handled by NGRX. No watches. NgModel wont work
    template: `
      <h1>Podcasts Search</h1>
      <div>
        <input name="searchValue" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" ><button type="submit" (click)="doSearch()">Search</button>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div *ngIf="showChannels">

        <h2>Found the following channels</h2>
        <div *ngFor="let channel of channels$ | async" (click)="loadChannel( channel )">{{channel.trackName}}</div>
      </div>
    `,
  })

  export class PodcastSearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
    channels$: Observable<Channel[]>;
    searchValue: string;
    showChannels = false;

    constructor(
      private store: Store<fromStore.PodcastsState>,

    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

      this.channels$ = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllChannels).pipe(
        filter(channels => !!channels.length),
        // channels.length should always be truthy at this point
        tap(channels => {
          console.log('channels', !!channels.length, channels);
          this.showChannels = !!channels.length;
         }),
      );
    // this.store.select( fromStore.getAllChannels ).subscribe( channels =>{
    //   console.log('channels', !!channels.length, channels);
    //   this.channels$ =  of ( channels );
    //   this.showChannels = !!channels.length;
    //   this.ref.markForCheck();
    // } );

    }

  doSearch() {
    console.log( 'search', this.searchValue );
    this.store.dispatch( new fromStore.LoadChannels( this.searchValue ) );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ngIf` `as` syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable)

```
*ngIf="channels$ | async as channels"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple subscriptions and they are not nested you can also use [`share`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) or [`shareReplay(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html). If all of the subscriptions are done at the same time go with `share` otherwise you should use `shareReplay(1)`.